# Problem with my test class: System.DmlException: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

Yesterday i worked on my test class and its up to %79 code coverage only 16 lines not tested. And failures are here:

> Line 221. System.ListException: Missing id at index: 0
>
> line 221 is delete(ordlist); after test start

Here is my test class:

```
    @isTest (SeeAllData=true)

public with sharing class CreatingOrderLineItemTest {
    
    static testMethod void myUnitTestInsert(){

Profile profiles=[Select Id From Profile Where Name='System Administrator'];

User newuser=new User(
profileid=profiles.Id,
email='deneme@deneme.com',
username='deneme1@deneme1.com',
lastname='deneme',
alias='deneme1',
languagelocalekey='en_US',
emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
localesidkey='en_US',
timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles');

insert newuser;

String pricebookid = '';
List<Pricebook2> pb2 = [select Id,name,isActive from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];
for(Pricebook2 pbb:pb2){
pricebookid = pbb.Id;

Product2 p2 = new Product2(Name='Test Product',isActive=true);
insert p2;

PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id=pricebookid, Product2Id=p2.Id, UnitPrice=99, isActive=true);
insert pbe;

Opportunity testOpportunity=new Opportunity(
Name = 'Test 1',
StageName ='Closed Won',
CloseDate= System.today(),
Pricebook2Id=pbe.Pricebook2Id,
Amount=50000);
insert testOpportunity;
List<Opportunity> opplist=new List<Opportunity>{testOpportunity};

Order__c testOrder=new Order__c(
Opportunity__c=testopportunity.id,
Name = 'Test 2',
StageName__c ='Closed Won',
CloseDate__c= System.today(),
Amount__c=50000
);
insert testOrder;



OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(PriceBookEntryId=pbe.Id, OpportunityId=testOpportunity.Id, Quantity=1, TotalPrice=99);
List <OpportunityLineItem> olilist=new List<OpportunityLineItem>{oli};
insert (olilist);

Order_Line_Item__c neworderlineitem=new Order_Line_Item__c();
List<Order_Line_Item__c> ordlist=new List <Order_Line_Item__c>();

for(OpportunityLineItem oppor:olilist){
    neworderlineitem.Quantity__c=oppor.Quantity;
    //neworderlineitem.TotalPrice__c=oppor.TotalPrice;
    neworderlineitem.Order__c=testOrder.Id;
    ordlist.add(neworderlineitem);
}
Test.startTest();

System.runAs(newuser){
insert(ordlist);

List<Order_Line_Item__c> ordlists=[Select Id,Quantity__c,TotalPrice__c,Order__c,Product2__c From Order_Line_Item__c Where id=:oli.Id];
for (Order_Line_Item__c ord:ordlists){
system.assertEquals(ord.Quantity__c,1);
system.assertEquals(ord.TotalPrice__c,99);
}
}
Test.stopTest();
}
}
    static testMethod void myUnitTestUpdate(){

Profile profiles=[Select Id From Profile Where Name='System Administrator'];

User newuser=new User(
profileid=profiles.Id,
email='deneme@deneme.com',
username='deneme1@deneme1.com',
lastname='deneme',
alias='deneme1',
languagelocalekey='en_US',
emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
localesidkey='en_US',
timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles');

insert newuser;

String pricebookid = '';
List<Pricebook2> pb2 = [select Id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];
for(Pricebook2 pbb:pb2){
pricebookid = pbb.Id;


Opportunity testOpportunity=new Opportunity(
Name = 'Test 1',
StageName ='Closed Won',
CloseDate= System.today(),
Amount=50000);
insert testOpportunity;
List<Opportunity> opplist=new List<Opportunity>{testOpportunity};

Order__c testOrder=new Order__c(
Opportunity__c=testOpportunity.id,
Name = 'Test 2',
StageName__c ='Closed Won',
CloseDate__c= System.today(),
Amount__c=50000
);
insert testOrder;

Product2 p2 = new Product2(Name='Test Product',isActive=true);
insert p2;

PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id=pricebookid, Product2Id=p2.Id, UnitPrice=99, isActive=true);
insert pbe;

OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(PriceBookEntryId=pbe.Id, OpportunityId=testOpportunity.Id, Quantity=1, TotalPrice=99);
List <OpportunityLineItem> olilist=new List<OpportunityLineItem>{oli};
insert (olilist);

oli.Quantity=2;
update(oli);

Order_Line_Item__c neworderlineitem=new Order_Line_Item__c();
List<Order_Line_Item__c> ordlist=new List <Order_Line_Item__c>();

for(OpportunityLineItem oppor:olilist){
    neworderlineitem.Quantity__c=oppor.Quantity;
    //neworderlineitem.TotalPrice__c=oppor.TotalPrice;
    neworderlineitem.Order__c=testOrder.Id;
    ordlist.add(neworderlineitem);
}
Test.startTest();

System.runAs(newuser){
insert(ordlist);

List<Order_Line_Item__c> ordlists=[Select Id,Quantity__c,TotalPrice__c,Order__c From Order_Line_Item__c Where id=:oli.Id];
for (Order_Line_Item__c ord:ordlists){
system.assertEquals(ord.Quantity__c,2);
system.assertEquals(ord.TotalPrice__c,99);
}
}
Test.stopTest();
}
}
static testMethod void myUnitTestDelete(){

Profile profiles=[Select Id From Profile Where Name='System Administrator'];

User newuser=new User(
profileid=profiles.Id,
email='deneme@deneme.com',
username='deneme1@deneme1.com',
lastname='deneme',
alias='deneme1',
languagelocalekey='en_US',
emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
localesidkey='en_US',
timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles');

insert newuser;

String pricebookid = '';
List<Pricebook2> pb2 = [select Id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];
for(Pricebook2 pbb:pb2){
pricebookid = pbb.Id;


Opportunity testOpportunity=new Opportunity(
Name = 'Test 1',
StageName ='Closed Won',
CloseDate= System.today(),
Amount=50000);
insert testOpportunity;
List<Opportunity> opplist=new List<Opportunity>{testOpportunity};

Order__c testOrder=new Order__c(
Opportunity__c=testOpportunity.id,
Name = 'Test 2',
StageName__c ='Closed Won',
CloseDate__c= System.today(),
Amount__c=50000
);
insert testOrder;

Product2 p2 = new Product2(Name='Test Product',isActive=true);
insert p2;

PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id=pricebookid, Product2Id=p2.Id, UnitPrice=99, isActive=true);
insert pbe;

OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(PriceBookEntryId=pbe.Id, OpportunityId=testOpportunity.Id, Quantity=1, TotalPrice=99);
List <OpportunityLineItem> olilist=new List<OpportunityLineItem>{oli};
insert (olilist);

oli.Quantity=2;
update(oli);

Order_Line_Item__c neworderlineitem=new Order_Line_Item__c();
List<Order_Line_Item__c> ordlist=new List <Order_Line_Item__c>();

for(OpportunityLineItem oppor:olilist){
    neworderlineitem.Quantity__c=oppor.Quantity;
    //neworderlineitem.TotalPrice__c=oppor.TotalPrice;
    neworderlineitem.Order__c=testOrder.Id;
    ordlist.add(neworderlineitem);
}
Test.startTest();

System.runAs(newuser){
delete(ordlist);

List<Order_Line_Item__c> ordlists=[Select Id,Quantity__c,TotalPrice__c,Order__c From Order_Line_Item__c Where id=:oli.Id];
for (Order_Line_Item__c ord:ordlists){
system.assertEquals(ord.Quantity__c,0);
system.assertEquals(ord.TotalPrice__c,0);
}
}
Test.stopTest();
}
}
}
```

Comment: ferhat, can you try edit your question to made the code look more readable ? You can use the {} icon in the editor.  It is also not entirely clear what your question is, do you not understand the error message, or do you have a question on writing test code ?

Comment: i am trying solve this problem. but didn't find any way.can you help me fix it.

Comment: It would be great if you mark the line on the code which is throwing the error as its difficult for us to identify the line nos

Comment: Do you understand the error ? Or is that your primary problem in solving it. If we need to help YOU, we need to know where YOU have a problem. Fixing code is easy, but the goal is learning you how to fix it.

Comment: i get error after Test.startTest() at insert(ordlist).i think problem system can't find the right order id for create orderlineitem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
neworderlineitem.Order__c=oppor.OpportunityId;
```

is what is causing the problem.

oppor.OpportunityId is an Opportunity ID, and you are trying to assign it to the field Order__c which is expecting an Order ID.

Comment: yea i just noticed it. i am trying find right value for it.

Comment: thx i fixed it now same failure for delete(ordlist).This time it saying Missing id at index:0 Line 221. i will edit my code at line 221

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're assigning the wrong id; 006b00000065Hl1AAE is an id for an Opportunity, which the field `Order__c` doesn't like. I suggest you check `OpportunityLineItem.Order__c` and see what object it is a lookup for and adjust your code.

Comment: Order_Line_Item__c have lookup to Order__c.

Comment: thx i fixed it now same failure for delete(ordlist).This time it saying Missing id at index:0 Line 221. i will edit my code at line 221